# Drupal 8 pass variable from parent paragraph to child paragrap in a twig file

Tags: drupal, twig

In Drupal 8 I have a paragraph called gallery with 2 fields. Inside the first field I can reference another paragraph (gallery image paragraph) and the other field is a Boolean field. On the parent paragraph I can access the Boolean field like this:

```
{{ paragraph.field_single_item.value }}
```

I like to access this variable from the child paragraph. Something like:

```
{%  parent_paragraph.paragraph.field_single_item.value %}
```

How do I do that?
Thank you

Comment: You can always use a hook to render the variable you want with theme_preprocess_paragraph. I think this is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I access the parent values by loading the parent paragraph via [Twig Tweak module](https://drupal.org/project/twig_tweak), then getting the values I need.

In your child paragraph, you could do something like this:

```
{% set paragraph_parent = drupal_entity('paragraph', paragraph.parent_id.value, 'default') %}
{% set single_item_value = paragraph_parent['#paragraph'].field_single_item.value %}

{% if single_item_value == 1 %}
    {# Do stuff #}
{% else %}
    {# Do something else #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also get the parent paragraph natively, without Twig Tweak:

```
{% set paragraph_parent = paragraph.getParentEntity() %}
{% set single_item_value = paragraph_parent.field_single_item.value %}

{% if single_item_value == 1 %}
    {# Do stuff #}
{% else %}
    {# Do something else #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is it impact the performance?  
{% set paragraph_parent = paragraph.getParentEntity() %}